# How do I pass a callback function to an akka actor constructor when using Context.actorOf?

Tags: scala, akka

I want to pass a callback to an akka actor in its constructor:

```
object FSMActorWithCallback {
  type Tracer = (Int, NodeState, NodeData, ActorRef, Any) => Unit
}

class FSMActorWithCallback(tracerCallback: FSMActorWithCallback.Tracer) extends FSMAwesomeActor
  // method is called each FSM Event so we can record current state and next message 
  override def trace(state: NodeState, data: NodeData, sender: ActorRef, msg: Any) : Unit = {
    // different tracing callback for different test rigs such as unit tests or integration tests
    tracerCallback(nodeUniqueId, state, data, sender, msg)
  }
}
```

This would let me define raw actor using `new` but I need to use the `actorOf` factory method to have the actor correctly hooked into the system:

```
class Supervisor extends Actor {

  def outputStateTrace(state: NodeState, data: NodeData, sender: ActorRef, msg: Any): Unit = { 
    /*actually make a binary log for analysis of complex failures*/
  }

  // COMPILE ERROR "follow this method with _ if you wan to treat it as a partially applied function" 
  var child = contact.actorOf(Props(classOf[FSMActorWithCallback], outputStateTracer) 

  // seems to work fine but not what i need
  val childRaw = new FSMActorWithCallback(tracer) 

}
```

The actual construction of the actor needs to be by the factory method shown but I cannot figure out how to pass a callback through the factory method.

Comment: Did you try doing what the compiler told you to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a method not a function. The compiler is telling you to use an Eta expansion to turn it into a function.

`var child = contact.actorOf(Props(classOf[FSMActorWithCallback], outputStateTracer _)`

As explained in the bottom of [this post](https://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/functional-scala-turning-methods-into-functions/):

> Since we’ve already introduced the magical underscore as a
>   jack-of-all-trades while discovering some shortcuts within function
>   definition, he’s again on board if we want to initiate eta expansion
>   more explicitly. So the second option to force the compiler to coerce
>   the second method into a function is to explicitly refering to the
>   methods so called method value, simply by quoting some underscore
>   [after] the method name (instead of the methods arguments)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: indeed. i asked not out of laziness but exactly because the amount of research to figure this out seemed disproportionate to other problems encountered in the past and I am looking to accept an answer which makes it obvious on this page to the next person how to do something like. of course a link to more detail is excellent but isn't actual answering the question which I made detailed with code exactly to make it easier for others to follow to a full conclusion expecting a snippet of code in the answer I will accept. thanks!

Comment: Well as Ryan already said, the compiler error has already answered your question.  `var child = contact.actorOf(Props(classOf[FSMActorWithCallback], outputStateTrace _)`  I assume outputStateTrace(r) is a typo, also outputSpaceTrace needs to take an int as the first parameter to match the signature of Tracer. If you want to understand what _ does then google Eta expansion or look at the previous link

Comment: It's probably not the done think to ask to be voted up but since I made your answer clear, accepted it, and voted it up could you be so kind as to vote up my question? :-)